# Can European Union countries make vaccination against COVID-19 compulsory?

Tags: european-union, human-rights, covid-19, schengen, vaccination

- Malta bans unvaccinated travellers
- France makes COVID-19 vaccine mandatory for health workers
  Macron considers "vaccination compulsory for the entire population"

These are two countries from the European Union and Schengen Area, making vaccination compulsory.

However, isn't this completely against of what's been approved by the Parliament?

https://pace.coe.int/en/files/29004/html

> 7.3.1 ensure that citizens are informed that the **vaccination is not mandatory** and that **no one is under political, social or other pressure to be vaccinated** if they do not wish to do so;
>
> 7.3.2 ensure that **no one is discriminated against for not having been vaccinated**, due to possible health risks **or not wanting to be vaccinated**;

Comment: You are mixing up the European Union (EU) and the Council of Europe (CoE), but these are 2 completely different organizations. The link you provided is a resolution of the Parliamentary Assembly of the Council of Europe (PACE). This resolution is not (legally) binding, it's basically just a recommendation or advice (see also the words "The Assembly thus urges member States and the European Union to ..."). In any case, PACE has no power to order or compel the members states to do or not to do something.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questioner does not seek an answer based on law, but political validation or use the question as a political statement. See comments and responses.

Comment: As currently written, the question seems like it could be answered based on the law.

Answer (score 1):

1. The ECDC and the European Parliament with the approval of the European Council probably has such power.
2. It is. But neither the Council of Europe nor any of its bodies have the power to create binding laws on any of its 47 member states.

Comment: So what is the point of those rules above if the Parliament has no power anyway? Seems to be giving hope to the citizens, only for that hope to be destroyed by the government doing the opposite anyway. I feel this is going against human rights. I don't want to be forced to take the vaccine until this new technology is fully tested for several years, like other vaccines. I am not at an age of risk.

Comment: It’s a report, it’s not a rule. Governments can receive advice from any one and then they will still go ahead and act within their power.

Comment: If you are not looking for an answer on the law but one on political rationale than this must be moved to politics.SE.

Comment: For those confused and downvoting, the European Council and the Council of Europe are not the same intergovernmental entities; the latter is not a body of the European Union at all. (Please see the succinct comment of n00p above!)

Comment: "neither the Council of Europe nor any of its bodies have the power to create binding laws" - While the CoE has much less binding power than the EU for example, as a blanket statement this is arguably incorrect especially viewed from a common law perspective... In theory, the court (ECtHR) produces **binding** judgments based on the text of the Convention, establishing its own body of evolving case law. Enforcement is another matter entirely though...

Comment: That's an argument of semantics. Case law is an interpretation of law and while binding (in civil matters effectively retrospectively), it is still not an act of legislation.